# Is there a way to find YouTube users by country/city?

Tags: youtube

I was wondering if there was a way to search for YouTube users from a specific country (UK) and if possible a specific city.

I know each user’s channel has the option to fill out country and city location.

I was thinking it would be good to find musicians from YouTube in a specific area an ask them if they want to meet up.

I know there are forums for this sort of thing but it would be great if you could search YouTube in this way as you can instantly hear what they are into.

So, is it possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You have to do a little script for that.

Check this resource: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/youtube

And there other ways to find YouTube users. There are a lot listed here: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/youtube/mashups